# Magento 2.4.4 upgrade after custom sorting filter Ascending/Discending order not working with porto theme?

Tags: catalog, sorting, magento2.4.4, product-sorting, magento2.3.7

I have upgrade Magento version 2.3.7 to Magento 2.4.4, before upgrade custom sorting option is working fine.after upgrade popularity asc/desc sorting is not working. we are currently using smartwave porto theme.

step 1 : I have created **di.xml** file on our extension etc directory.

app/code/Vendor/Extension/etc/frontend

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="sorting_add_custom_options" type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Model\Config" />
    </type>
   <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="catalog_productlist_toolbar_plugin" type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
    </type>
</config>
```

step :2 I have added option using **config.php** file on the below file path.

app/code/Vendor/Extension/Plugin/Model

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Model;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Config  {


    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }


    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
    {
        $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
        $currencySymbol = $store->getCurrentCurrency()->getCurrencySymbol();

        // Remove specific default sorting options
        $default_options = [];
        // $default_options['popularityorder'] = $options['popularityorder'];

        unset($options['relevance']);
        unset($options['position']);
        unset($options['name']);
        unset($options['price']);
        unset($options['popularityorder']);
        unset($options['discountpercent']);

        //Changing label
        $customOption['popularity_asc'] = __( 'Popularity - High to Low' );
        $customOption['popularity_desc'] = __( 'Popularity - Low to High' );
        
        //Changing label
        $customOption['price_desc'] = __( 'Price - High to Low' );
        $customOption['price_asc'] = __( 'Price - Low to High' );

        //Changing label
        $customOption['discount_desc'] = __( 'Discount % - High to Low' );
        $customOption['discount_asc'] = __( 'Discount % - Low to High' );

        $default_options['popularityorder'] = $customOption['popularityorder'];
        $customOption['popularityorder'] = $default_options['popularityorder'];

        //Merge default sorting options with custom options
        $options = array_merge($customOption, $options);

        return $options;
    }
}
```

Step 3 : after that i have created the below file path **Toolbar.php** plugin.

app/code/Vendor/Extension/Plugin/Product/ProductList

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar
{

  public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    ) {
        $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
        $result = $proceed($collection);

        if ($currentOrder) {
         if ($currentOrder == 'popularity_asc') {
                 $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('popularityorder', 'asc');
            }
            if ($currentOrder == 'popularity_desc') {
                $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('popularityorder', 'desc');
            }
            if ($currentOrder == 'price_asc') {
                $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'asc');
            }
            if ($currentOrder == 'price_desc') {
                $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'desc');
            }
            if ($currentOrder == 'discount_asc') {
                $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('discountpercent', 'asc');
            }
            if ($currentOrder == 'discount_desc') {
                $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('discountpercent', 'desc');
            }           
        }

        return $result;
    }

}
```